# Accessing Joomla Environment withOUT the CMS

Tags: joomla3.0

At long last, we're migrating a number of J1.5 sites to J3.2.  Along with the native code, we have a number of internal standalone scripts that relied on loading and accessing everything in Joomla without going through the CMS and conventional MVC of Components/Modules/Plugins.  We primarily used the logged in $user and $db objects extensively along with 3rd party API to accomplish a number of internal functions.

The way we accomplished this in J1.5 was as follows:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define ('JPATH_BASE', "c:\\wamp\\www\\oursite");
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES.DS.'joomla'.DS.'import.php'); // Joomla library imports.
    global $mainframe;
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
}
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

I've spent the weekend trying to accomplish the same thing with J32 with little success - obviously, J32 is quite different from J15, but the new terms "Platform", "API", and "Framework" return millions of results that have no real relevance.  I also understand that the "Joomla Framework" gives enormous possibilities, but we don't have the resources to rewrite everything using those possibilities, so we just want to replicate the above code for our internal pages that use the 3rd party API while the bulk of the work is in migrating the site that the world sees and uses.

Is there a way to accomplish the above code in Joomla 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following which I have made a few tweaks to. I have tested this just now on my localhost running Joomla 3.2.1 with a database query and user object.

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define ('JPATH_BASE', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\oursite');

    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
}
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: somehow I know it would be you that answered this question....after a very long night, I was able to come close to this with some tinkering with the code at http://docs.joomla.org/Framework:Creating_a_Stand-alone_Application#Building_a_Web_Application_on_the_Framework.  Thanks!!!